# Name Error in Python, even when name is defined

Tags: python, list, helper, nameerror

So I my function uses 3 parameters. I created one helper function that uses one of those three. The helper works perfectly fine.
However, when I call it in the main function, it gives me name error and says that the name of the parameter isn't defined.

The helper creates a list. so I call it like

```
new_list = helper_function(parameter)
```

And it doesn't work.

this is a very messy code because I am working on it currently

```
#HELPERS
def create_list_of_vowels(phonemes):
    '''
    Returns a list of vowels from all phonemes
    >>>create_list_of_vowels(['AE1', 'B', 'S', 'IH0', 'N', 'TH']):
    ['AE1', 'IH0']
    '''
    number = ('0', '1', '2')
    vowels = []
    for i in phonemes:
        if i[-1] in number:
            vowels.append(i)
    return vowels

def clean_up(s):
    """ (str) -> str

    Return a new string based on s in which all letters have been
    converted to uppercase and punctuation characters have been stripped
    from both ends. Inner punctuation is left untouched.

    >>> clean_up('Birthday!!!')
    'BIRTHDAY'
    >>> clean_up('"Quoted?"')
    'QUOTED'
    """

    punctuation = """!"'`@$%^&_-+={}|\\/,;:.-?)([]<>*#\n\t\r"""
    result = s.upper().strip(punctuation)
    return result

def every_line_to_list(poem_lines):
    """
    Return every string converted into a list of strings

    >>>every_line_to_list(['The first line leads off,', 'With a gap before the next.', 'Then the poem ends.'])
    [['The', 'first', 'line', 'leads', 'off,'], ['With', 'a', 'gap', 'before', 'the', 'next'], ['Then', 'the', 'poem', 'ends.']
    >>>every_line_to_list()
    """
    return [x.split() for x in poem_lines]
#========================================================


def check_vowel_phoneme_counts(poem_lines, pattern, word_to_phonemes):
    r""" (list of str, poetry pattern, pronunciation dictionary) -> list of str

    Precondition: len(poem_lines) == len(pattern[0])

    Return a list of lines from poem_lines that do not have the right number of
    vowel phonemes for the poetry pattern according to the pronunciation dictionary.
    If all lines have the right number of vowel phonemes, return the empty list.

    >>> poem_lines = ['The first line leads off,', 'With a gap before the next.', 'Then the poem ends.']
    >>> pattern = ([5, 5, 4], ['*', '*', '*'])
    >>> word_to_phonemes = {'NEXT': ['N', 'EH1', 'K', 'S', 'T'],
    ...                     'GAP': ['G', 'AE1', 'P'],
    ...                     'BEFORE': ['B', 'IH0', 'F', 'AO1', 'R'],
    ...                     'LEADS': ['L', 'IY1', 'D', 'Z'],
    ...                     'WITH': ['W', 'IH1', 'DH'],
    ...                     'LINE': ['L', 'AY1', 'N'],
    ...                     'THEN': ['DH', 'EH1', 'N'],
    ...                     'THE': ['DH', 'AH0'], 
    ...                     'A': ['AH0'], 
    ...                     'FIRST': ['F', 'ER1', 'S', 'T'], 
    ...                     'ENDS': ['EH1', 'N', 'D', 'Z'],
    ...                     'POEM': ['P', 'OW1', 'AH0', 'M'],
    ...                     'OFF': ['AO1', 'F']}
    >>> check_vowel_phoneme_counts(poem_lines, pattern, word_to_phonemes)
    ['With a gap before the next.', 'Then the poem ends.']
    >>> poem_lines = ['The first line leads off,']
    >>> check_vowel_phoneme_counts(poem_lines, ([0], ['*']), word_to_phonemes)
    []
    """
#split into list of lists 

new_poem_lines = every_line_to_list(poem_lines)

# CLEAN UP STRINGS (REMOVE PUNCTUATION)

for line1 in new_poem_lines:
    for word in line1:
        word = clean_up(word)

# Find each word in the string in the word_to_phonemes
# return list of all vowels, calculate them
# if number of vowels does not equal to pattern[i], append to list
```

===================================================

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
Python Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
poem_lines = ['The first line leads off,', 'With a gap before the next.', 'Then the poem ends.']
check_vowel_phoneme_counts(poem_lines, pattern, word_to_phonemes)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
builtins.NameError: name 'check_vowel_phoneme_counts' is not defined
```

Comment: Post your code and error please

Comment: So where did you define `parameter` *in the calling code*? You are passing in a value for that function argument here, so you need to actually have something to pass in.

Comment: What LittlePanda said: we can't help you debug code that we cannot see. So _please_ post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Posted, sorry about that

Comment: Can you please include the **full** error message in your question?

Comment: Did it, happens even if I define poem_lines is defined in shell

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that variable 'poem_lines' is not defined. You need to assign something to it before passing it as an argument to function every_line_to_list(). Example:

```
poem_lines = ['The first line leads off,', 'With a gap before the next.', 'Then the poem ends.']
new_poem_lines = every_line_to_list(poem_lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

You define check_vowel_phoneme_counts(...):

But then you have no code that is indented under your definition.  If the code below your docstring is supposed to be in the function, then it must be indented.

Python won't let you define a function with no statements.

```
def check_vowel_phoneme_counts(poem_lines, pattern, word_to_phonemes):
#split into list of lists 

new_poem_lines = every_line_to_list(poem_lines)

for line1 in new_poem_lines:
    for word in line1:
        word = clean_up(word)
```